# how to use a field of other table in view using foreign key in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, foreign-keys

I have two tables 'teams' and 'users'. in users I have a foreign key("current_team_ID) for 'ID' field in 'teams' table.
Now I want to see in our view the name of a team of users.

This is my controller code:

```
public function index() {
    $user = User::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
    $current_team_id = Teams::pluck('title', 'id');
    
    return view('admin.users.index')->with(compact('user', 'current_team_id'));
}
```

And the index code :

```
@foreach ($user as $item )
    <tr class="tableRows">
        <td>{{ $item->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->stateID }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->current_team_id }}</td>
    </tr>    
@endforeach
```

It just shows the 'ID' of the team but I want to show the title of that. what should I do?
thanks

**usersModel**

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable {
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'mobile',
        'personalCode' ,
        'email',
        'password',
        'stateID',
        'lastLoginDateTime',
        'token'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];
}
```

**teamsModel**

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Teams extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'teams';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false ;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the model class please ?

Comment: model of users or teams ?

Comment: both of them users and teams

Comment: you can check the answer now,

Answer (score 0):

if the user-team has relation defined you can do this in User model

```
public function team()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
}

public function get_team_name()
{
  if($this->team()->exists()) {    // check if the user have a related team
    return $this->team->title;
  }
}
```

then in the blade loop you can

```
<td>{{ $item->get_team_name() }}</td>
```

Comment: thanks ... I added both models up.It seems there is no relation . Is it right ?

Comment: no, you don't. Declare the relation between, i'm going to update my code for user, you finish the team model as the relation you define, I think is hasMany ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First let's create the relatations

Add this to the `User` class

```
public function team(){
 return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
}
```

Add this to Teams class

```
 public function users(){
     return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
```

And if you want to access a user

```
  $users =  Teams::find(1)->with('users')->get();
  return view('admin.users.index')->with(compact('users');
```

And if you want to display a team with users

```
 @foreach($users as $user)
            <td>$user->team->title </td>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks 
just I don't understand clear part 3. should I replace that with my index function ?? because I want to show some fields of users ( like name , id , etc ) and one filed of teams in my list.

Comment: If you want to write user data just write $user->name $user->id etc

Answer (score 0):

```
=>add on your users table.

$table->foreign('current_team_id')->references('id')->on('teams')->onDelete('cascade');

=>add relationship on Users Model

    public function team()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(Teams::class, 'id', 'current_team_id');
        }

=>you can access directly use team relationship in the user index file.
 <td>{{$item->team->title}}</td>
```